# mod_rewrite file check with extention

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess for simple url rewriting for any MVC architecture.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /personal/site/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Every thing is working only **one exception** rises. On the root where `index.php` exists i created a file `generator.js`, i also do have a controller named generator.

So for a request, `http://localhost/personal/site/generator/css`,

it must rewrite it to  `http://localhost/personal/site/index.php/generator/css`

But it is rewriting it to `http://localhost/personal/site/generator.js/css`

How to resolve this scenario?

Comment: There is only one rewrite rule in your question and it can't produce the effect you describe.  You might want to have a look around for another rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you please suggest me what other rule i should add to get my effect?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution from stack-overflow and the solution is to Turn of multiviews.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

This solved the problem.

The credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/567986/gerben